# eBay API affiliation: No affiliate link in API respons

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to use the eBay API to retrieve affiliation links through their search API service. I can make calls to the API and get the expected results but all links I get in return are standard links instead of affiliate links.

I have tried to make calls with two different endpoints:

1. http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=FindProducts&responseencoding=XML&appid=MY_APP_ID&siteid=0&QueryKeywords=nvidia&version=967&trackingId=MY_TRACKING_ID&MaxEntries=20&networkId=0
2. http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=MY_APP_ID&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&keywords=rtx+2080+ti&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3&trackingId=MY_TRACKING°ID&networkId=9

In both cases I get the results I had expected but links are standard links like this one:

```
 [viewItemURL] => http://www.ebay.com/itm/EVGA-Geforce-RTX-2080-Ti-XC-ULTRA-Brand-New-HAND-FAST-SHIPPING-/292812915006
```

I'm probably missing something but I can't see what's wrong. Do you have any idea?

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affiliate tracking parameters are different for Shopping API and Finding API.

For Finding, I think you need to use "&affiliate.networkId=9", etc.

For Shopping, just don't use the FindProducts call at all; it's broken. Use the corresponding call from the Finding API instead.